# How can I get jpg file in Imageview?

Tags: android

I have Android code as follows. It is a RecyclerView which get title and Image and display List. I am trying to get title and image from another  activity class.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.mBoundString = mValues.get(position).getId();
    holder.txtTourName.setText(mValues.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.imgTourIcon.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(mValues.get(position).getImage1()));

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onTourSelected(mValues.get(position));
        }
    });

    }
```

I have got the following error when try to run.

```
Invalid int: "255d13aaccb9e941.jpg"
```

I understand what does this error mean but I don't know the way that how can I get image and set it to ImageView.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce]. Where is `255d13aaccb9e941.jpg` stored? What is `mValues`?

Comment: What does return this function : `mValues.get(position).getImage1()` a simple string or a Bitmap ? `setImageResource` is going to set a drawable as the content of this ImageView. So maybe you should use `setImageBitmap` instead of `setImageResource`

Comment: @Snoobie  it returns string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your code is not looking clear, as far as I understand, you are trying to use .setImageResource(int id) by calling .setImageResource(String). You need to find id of the image you are trying to set. 
So instead of this `holder.imgTourIcon.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(mValues.get(position).getImage1()));`

try this

`int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(Integer.parseInt(mValues.get(position).getImage1(), "drawable", "android"));
holder.imgTourIcon.setImageResource(id);`
(*Of course, in here, I'm assuming your JPG is in the drawable folder*)

Comment: `Resources.getSystem()` returns Resource object of your application. You can check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getSystem())

Comment: Also, forgot to say, if Resources.getSystem() gives you an error somehow, you might want to use `getResources().getIdentifier( ... ` . According to some, this gives better results for some cases.

Comment: It gives error that can not resolve method getResources.

Comment: I'm not sure where are you using thi but can you try this `getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier( .. ` ? If that fails, you need to pass contex in your class. But If you are calling it from Activity, you can directly call it by `this.getResources()`

Comment: I have tried by passing context and its worked. Thank you.. :)